# Android How to change Popup Menu Item Background

Tags: android, styles, popupmenu

I am using a Popup menu.
I want to change the background of popup menu but not finding a way to do it.
I don't want alert dialog type functonality.

I have a button and on the click listener I initialize a popup menu.

```
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), v);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        };
        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

In the menu folder I have popup.xml.
I want to change the background of the items of popup menu(not the button).How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem using this code:

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.PopupMenu);
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);
```

reference: blog.stylingandroid.com

Comment: This helped me. Thanks Marcus.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can use style.

Do not know exactly but one of those if changed in your theme should do the job. Change background in styles to your custom drawables.

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/yourPopupWindowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/yourPopupWindowStyle</item>
```